# Creation and adding of a class to an array leads to weird result - Java

Tags: java, brute-force

I have been stuck with a behavior of my code that I can not explain myself. I will post the relevant code and then ask the question:

```
//Uses brute force and existing functions to create and check for equilibria
static void getEquis(List<Integer> values, int depth) {
  if (values.size() == depth) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++) {
      agents[i].setVote(values.get(i).intValue());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++) {
      agents[i].setDoVote(true);
      if(isEqui()==true) {
        int votes[] = new int[numOfAgents];
        boolean doVotes[] = new boolean[numOfAgents];
        for(int j = 0; j < numOfAgents; j++) {
          votes[j] = 5;
          doVotes[j] = true;
          //votes[j] = agents[j].getVote();
          //doVotes[j] = agents[j].getDoVote();
        }
        addEqui(new Equi(votes, doVotes));
      }
      agents[i].setDoVote(false);
      if(isEqui()==true) {
        int votes[] = new int[numOfAgents];
        boolean doVotes[] = new boolean[numOfAgents];
        for(int j = 0; j < numOfAgents; j++) {
          votes[j] = 5;
          doVotes[j] = true;
          //votes[j] = agents[j].getVote();
          //doVotes[j] = agents[j].getDoVote();
        }
        addEqui(new Equi(votes, doVotes));
      }
    }
```

Please note that I left the comments (votes[j] = agents[j].getVote();) in there intentionally, as this is what it is supposed to do, votes[j] = 5; and the following line are just for testing.

```
private static class Equi
{
  private int vote[] = new int[numOfAgents];
  private boolean doVote[] = new boolean[numOfAgents];   

  public Equi(int[] votes, boolean[] doVotes)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++) {
      this.vote[i] = votes[i];
      this.doVote[i] = doVotes[i];      
    }
  }
  public int[] getVote() {
    return this.vote;
  }
  public boolean[] getDoVote() {
    return this.doVote;
  }
  public void print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfAgents; i++) {
      System.out.println("Agent " + (i+1) + ": " + agents[i].doVote + " Wahl: " + agents[i].vote);
    }
    System.out.println("Solution: " + computeMean());
  }
}

//Adds a new equilibrium to the equilibria array
public static void addEqui(Equi equi)
{ 
  Equi store[] = new Equi[equilibria.length + 1]; 
  for(int i = 0; i< equilibria.length; i++) {
    store[i] = equilibria[i];
  }
  store[equilibria.length] = equi;
  equilibria = store;
}
```

Now if I print out the results of the equilibria array I get

> Agent 1: false Wahl: 100 Agent 2: false Wahl: 100 Solution: 0.0 Agent
>   1: false Wahl: 100 Agent 2: false Wahl: 100 Solution: 0.0 Agent 1:
>   false Wahl: 100 Agent 2: false Wahl: 100 Solution: 0.0 Agent 1: false
>   Wahl: 100 Agent 2: false Wahl: 100 Solution: 0.0

This is realised by running this in main:

```
for(int i = 0; i < equilibria.length; i++) {
  equilibria[i].print();
}
```

In my understanding it should always give me 5 and true but this behaviour is very weird for me. Do you have an explanation for this? If you need any other parts of the code please comment and I will edit and add it.

Comment: In cases like this, the debugger is your friend.

Comment: well, `agents[i].setDoVote(false);` would explain all the `false`s you got in your output.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. Robby, I have tried that but was not able to find the root of the problem. Eran, yes but above I set it to true and should it not be true anyways since what I'm giving addEqui is the array of just true values?

Comment: It resolved itself, I found my mistake in the print statement, which I did not look at because it was so simple. Sorry and thanks to everyone who gave this time!